# MVS Xamarin - different versions of Xamarin.iOS on my Mac and on my local Windows

Tags: ios, macos, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios

I only start my adventure with Xamarin.

In my Mac, I have installed OS X (v10.11.6), XCode (v7.3) and Xamarin Studio. I have logged in with my Xamarin account.

I have an error, when I try to connect to my Mac:

```
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.MacServer Error: 0 : [2016-09-24 16:48:19.0838] The installed Xamarin.iOS (version 9.6) on the Mac RamaX.local (192.168.209.128) is not compatible with the local Xamarin.iOS 10.0.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Update your Mac to `Xamarin.iOS` Version: 10.0.0.6 and `Xcode 8`, they have to be matching versions between the two installs...

Comment: Thanks for quick answer! I thought about this variant. But can I solve this problem on Windows side (and Visual Studio)? For example, downgrade `Xamarin.iOS` to version _9.6_ or to set minimum support version to _9.6_ in my iOS project.

Comment: Sure you can down upgrade your Xamarin install on Windows to match, but the versions need to match.

Comment: Could you tell me, which version of Xamarin contains `Xamarin.iOS 9.6`, because I can't find it?

Comment: The last Xamarin.iOS 9.6 is 9.6.2.4 is from https://releases.xamarin.com/stable-release-cycle-6-service-release-4/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!